# Some animal eating tulip head?

Tags: planting, pest-damage, tulips

I have some short tulips 12" tall and something or some animal seems to eat off the flower head

[image]

Do you know what it was and how to prevent it?

Thanks

Comment: In addition to the answer from Jurp squirrels will also eat tulips

Answer (score 1):

If you live outside the city in the suburbs or "the country", then that's deer damage, and there's no real way to prevent it except by fencing. There are some products that do work for a little while, but they need to be reapplied rather frequently and usually stink of either coyote urine or rotten eggs.

Comment: I have not found any sprays that work for long. I put wire cages ( 24") around small plants and the deer tip them over to eat the plants.

Comment: @blacksmith37 - When I lived in the country I never tried to restrain the deer - there were too many. I usually just planted poisonous plants (daffodils instead of tulips, for example). Young deer would still sample a flower or two, but would spit them out. Limits your plant palette, but reduces anxiety and sadness due to lost plants and flowers.